# {Android} Can I choose picture from gallery and send it to new activity in one button?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, gallery

I try to create image effect application
on main screen have button Camera, Paint, Gallery, Setting
I want to choose image from gallery and send it to new activity to add effect after click gallery button.
This is my Code

```
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
Bitmap temp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button gal = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bgal);

    gal.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Gallery.class);
            intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", temp);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        temp =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
    }

}
```

Can Fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
Bitmap temp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Button gal = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bgal);

gal.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

    }
});
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();

    temp =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);


        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Gallery.class);
        intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", temp);
        startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you but app don't go to new activity.It I can choose photo only.

Comment: any crash or not ..??

Comment: in logcat "failed binder transaction"

Comment: I can solves to by save image in cache before send and get it in new activity